# Jerky gradient in UIButton border

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, core-graphics, tvos

I need to create rounded UIButton with gradient in border. What did I miss in Core Graphics code ?

I created CAGradientLayer with mask.

```
        layer.cornerRadius = 43
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.frame = bounds
        gradient.colors = [UIColor(red: 0.99, green: 0.89, blue: 0.54, alpha: 1).cgColor, UIColor(red: 0.95, green: 0.51, blue: 0.51, alpha: 1).cgColor]
        gradient.locations = [0, 1]
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.83, y: -0.68)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.13, y: 0.82)
        gradient.cornerRadius = 43

        let shape = CAShapeLayer()
        shape.lineWidth = 6
        shape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: gradient.frame, cornerRadius: 43).cgPath
        shape.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        shape.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        gradient.mask = shape

        layer.addSublayer(gradient)
        setTitleColor(.red, for: .normal)
        titleLabel?.font = Theme.shared.font.bold(ofSize: 25.0)
        clipsToBounds = true
```

I expect not jerky gradient, evenly trimmed by mask.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by jerky gradient? what 2 colors you want? yellow and orange?

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is that a path's border is centered on the edge of the frame, so you need to inset the path by 1/2 the line width.

The second issue is that setting a layer's `.cornerRadius` does *not* give you the same curve as a rounded rect bezier path (odd, but that's the case). So, you need to create another mask to apply to the button's layer. It *can* result in artifacts at the edges, so inset it by 0.5 pts.

Try this modified code:

```
    // create gradient layer
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = bounds
    gradient.colors = [UIColor(red: 0.99, green: 0.89, blue: 0.54, alpha: 1).cgColor, UIColor(red: 0.95, green: 0.51, blue: 0.51, alpha: 1).cgColor]
    gradient.locations = [0, 1]
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.83, y: -0.68)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.13, y: 0.82)

    // create shape for gradient layer mask
    let gradientShape = CAShapeLayer()

    // edge / line width of 6
    gradientShape.lineWidth = 6

    // border is centered on the edge, so we want to inset the rect by 1/2 of the border width
    var r = bounds.insetBy(dx: 3, dy: 3)

    // create rounded rect path
    gradientShape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: r, cornerRadius: 43).cgPath

    // black stroke, clear fill
    gradientShape.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    gradientShape.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

    // assign the shape as the gradient layer's mask
    gradient.mask = gradientShape

    // create a new shape for the button's layer
    let layerShape = CAShapeLayer()

    // inset by 0.5, to avoid artifacts on the edges
    r = bounds.insetBy(dx: 0.5, dy: 0.5)

    // create rounded rect path
    layerShape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: r, cornerRadius: 43).cgPath

    // black fill (no stroke)
    layerShape.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

    // assign the shape as the layer's mask
    layer.mask = layerShape

    // add gradient layer as a sublayer
    layer.addSublayer(gradient)

    setTitleColor(.red, for: .normal)
    titleLabel?.font = Theme.shared.font.bold(ofSize: 25.0)
    clipsToBounds = true
```